# WIndows starts with Black Screen and Cursor

Tags: windows, black-screen-of-death

A friend has an old Windows 7 Laptop that starts up, shows the welcome screen as the default user is logged in, then everything disappears and they're left with a black screen with a cursor, and that's it. No start menu, no nothing.

How can they fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### We fixed this by

- Re-enabling the Administrator account by booting into `Safe mode with Command Prompt` by hitting `F8` when the computer is starting up, then running `net user administrator /active:yes1` in the Command prompt window. Then run `shutdown -r` to reboot the computer.
- Once it reboots, we had another user to login as (`Administrator`)
- Then from there I installed [Autoruns](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns) and disabled anything abnormal in Windows startup. I dont know if this really helped or not.
- I then rebooted into the other user account, and still had the black screen. I hit `Ctrl+Alt+Del` and then ran the Task Manager, and chose `File | Run` and ran `explorer.exe`. The desktop came back.
- I rebooted, and everything was fine.

I've since rebooted multiple times with no issues, and have installed anitvirus on the machine (NOD32) and no viruses were found.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this problem on a friend's Windows 7 laptop like this:

1. Boot into safe mode
2. Went into Devices and Printers
3. Locate "Display" driver
4. Uninstall driver
5. Reboot

After reboot, no more black screen. It was running on some generic video driver. From here, we reinstalled the Display driver from the internet, and everything was working good.